# How to make Create/Join group with Firebase in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, flutter-dependencies

I want to make a `Create/Join` group feature in the app where anyone can Create the group
and `share group ID` and let others people to join(By using firebase as backend). How can I achieve something like that. I need some explanation. What do I need to do or to implement?

***Just to keep in mind I don’t want to create chat group. This is more like a group that let users do things together like puzzle. Or like quizzes in Kahoot.***

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUb1f.jpg)

***I haven’t start to write yet so there won't be any code***

Answer (score 0):

Something i'm actually doing myself though my scenario is a little different as it's more focused on financial groups.
I can point you to a resource that's working for me though i'm still figuring it out myself,maybe it'll be of some help to you too(Note:it only shows how to create and join but doesn't go into how to make invites,but i think its a good start)

Source: [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t_sxlndzo1k)

Comment: Thanks. I am following this video tutorial too. But I don't know If it'll work cuz the video is old. Did it work for you?

Comment: I'm currently still working on the feature,it gave me an idea as to the approach(I didn't want to follow it line for line) so I'm still experimenting.I can only give you proper feedback in probably maybe a week once I have something solid,functional and tested.I was just hoping it could give you some direction as well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).